# RasPi - USB microphone locks up

Tags: raspberry-pi, lock, usb-audio

On my RasPi board, Debian Linux, the USB microphone occasionally gets locked up such that nothing can use it. The microphone has a LED which is usually flashing, when it's locked, it turns off.

The utility `arecord` describes it as follows:

```
card 1: Device [DYNEX USB MIC Device], device 0:USB Audio [USB Audio]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

When the microphone stops working, `arecord` gives diagnostics like this:

```
> arecord -D plughw:1,0 > recording.wav
Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
arecord: set_params:1145: Unable to install hw_params:
ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  U8
etc...
```

Unplugging and plugging the microphone fixes it, only because the current dip forces the RasPi to reboot! Not an ideal situation.

Is there a way to fix this from the command line or a C executable?

I also tried using `ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_RESET, 0)` using the output from `lsusb` to provide the bus and device number. That turns the LED back on, but it's overkill. The device has to be re-setup using alsamixer.

Comment: are you running it from a USB hub? The power draw from USB devices sometimes isn't enough, and might be causing hardware problems if not.

Comment: Same behavior is observed when using a hub or without. RasPi is connected to dedicated power supply as opposed to a USB port.

Comment: are you aware of this site too: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Yes, I thought this is more of a Linux question.

Comment: Do you have the same problems if you connect the mic to a normal Linux-PC? You can easily "create" one by booting a live distribution from a CD/USB flash drive.

Comment: I have experienced similar problems with an USB keyboard. Sometimes, the input just lags for several seconds at a time. Have you tried rebooting, disconnecting everything related to USB, only connect the powered USB hub and connect every USB device through that?

Comment: Why would a mic draw that much current? The inrush is probably due to charging some internal capacitors; it's not an indicator of the steady consumption.

Comment: A colleague had a similar problem with a keyboard and a USB hub being lost by their Rasberry Pi.  He replaced it with another Pi which eliminated the problem.  Our conclusion was that the Pi was faulty and either not providing enough power to the hub, or some other HW problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to solve.

Issue: Your microphone is not getting enough power. The Raspberry Pi USB ports have issues supplying enough amps to USB devices that need more than power than USB memory cards.

Solution: Get an active USB hub (powered hub plugged into a power source like an outlet.) The hub will power the microphone.